# Can I use scanf() function within printf() function giving a defined output?

Tags: programming-languages, c, coding-style

Can I use scanf() function within printf() function giving a defined output? If yes,then please explain me the **Output** for the simple code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
  int a;
  printf("%d",scanf("%d",&a));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do?  Note that the return value of `scanf` is the number of items matched...

Comment: You could, I would sack you for cramming so many of the worst C styles into one line..... ( a) It's wrong, b) if it not wrong, it not obviously right, c) Failing to check return values, d) multiple actions performed on one line. e) WTF is a comment for. (Note: Many of these overlap - for instance, a comment might have helped answer a) and b). )

Comment: @mattnnz You could try, but in many jurisdictions you would lose an action for wrongful dismissal. You would need to demonstrate misconduct or gross incompetence or negligence. I assume you are being rhetorical here.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly. `scanf` returns the number of items parsed, but what you can do is this:

```
printf("%d", (scanf("%d", &a), a));
```

Using the comma operator to discard the results of `scanf` and use the value of a instead.

Comment: But in c, order of evaluation of function argument is not specified. So how can you be sure that scanf("%d", &a) is going to evaluate first??

Comment: The comma expression introduces a sequence point. It's a lot of technical jargon, but it's important that I'm actually only passing two arguments to printf here - the format (`"%d"`), and `a`. The result of `scanf` is not passed to printf.

Comment: Yes comma operator introduces a sequence point. But here i don't think so it is used as an operator instead it is used as separator.
One more example which is always confusing.

void fun(f1(), f2());
/* Comma acts as a separator here and doesn't enforce any sequence. 
    Therefore, either f1() or f2() can be called first */

Answer (score 2):

`printf` and `scanf` are just functions.  You can use the output of one function as the parameter to another as you do above.

As @MichaelT notes in his comment, the return value of `scanf` is *not* the value read from the keyboard.  If you check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), it says:

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

In other words, in your example, it will either return `1`, if a valid integer is entered, or `0` if no valid integer is entered.

Answer (score 1):

As `scanf` returns the number of conversions that were successfully made, the example program will either print a `1`, a `0` or a `-1`, depending on the provided input (`1` if the start of the input is convertible to an integer, `0` for non-integer input, `-1` for input errors).

Answer (score 1):

**Easily Understandable**

In C, printf() returns the number of characters successfully written on the output and scanf() returns number of items successfully read.

For example, below program prints akp 3

```
int main()
{
  printf(" %d", printf("%s", "akp"));
  getchar();
}
```

Irrespective of the string user enters, below program prints 1.

```
int main()
{
  char a[50];  
  printf(" %d", scanf("%s", a));
  getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use printf() to output a function's return value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
  int a;
  printf("%d",scanf("%d",&a));
  return 0;
}
```

If you input a number. It'll output 1. It means the scanf() function was executed successfully, and the return value is 1.

---

If you input a letter. It'll output 0. It means the execution of the function directive fails: this condition is a matching failure. The return value is 0.